# Dataframe to dictionary of (row index, column name) as keys

Tags: python

How I can convert a dataframe to a dictionary where the keys are tuples of (row index, column name) and the values are the values of each cell?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this, which is not directly achievable with `DataFrame.to_dict`:

```
di = {}
for k1, v1 in df.to_dict().items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        di[(k1, k2)] = v2
```

Or in one line:

```
{(k1, k2): v2 for k1, v1 in df.to_dict().items() for k2, v2 in v1.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the python library pandas. In that case you can solve this like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "cat": [1, 2, 3],
    "mouse": [5, 10, 12],
    "dog": [1, 5, 10]
}, index=["age", "weight", "height"])

data_dict = df.to_dict('dict')

desired_result = dict()
for i in data_dict.keys():
    for v in data_dict[i].keys():
        desired_result[(i, v)] = data_dict[i][v]

print(desired_result)
# should out put the following:
```

{('cat', 'age'): 1,
('cat', 'weigth'): 2,
('cat', 'height'): 3,
('mouse', 'age'): 5,
('mouse', 'weigth'): 10,
('mouse', 'height'): 12,
('dog', 'age'): 1,
('dog', 'weigth'): 5,
('dog', 'height'): 10}